# How to double elements in an F# list and set them in a new list

Tags: list, function, recursion, f#, functional-programming

I am very new to F# and functional programming in general, and would like to recursively create a function that takes a list, and doubles all elements.

This is what I used to  search for a spacific element, but im not sure how exactly I can change it to do what I need.

```
let rec returnN n theList =
    match n, theList with
    | 0, (head::_) -> head
    | _, (_::theList') -> returnN (n - 1) theList'
    | _, [] -> invalidArg "n" "n is larger then list length"

let list1 = [5; 10; 15; 20; 50; 25; 30]   
printfn "%d" (returnN 3 list1 )
```

Is there a way for me to augment this to do what I need to?

Comment: When asking questions, you should always show how you've tried to solve your problem.  As your question stands, you're basically just asking someone to solve your problem for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to take you through the thinking process.

**Step 1.** I need a recursive function that takes a list and doubles all the elements:

So, let's implement this in a naive way:

```
let rec doubleAll list = 
    match list with
    | []       -> []
    | hd :: tl -> hd * 2 :: doubleAll tl
```

Hopefully this logic is quite simple:

If we have an empty list, we return another empty list.

If we have a list with at least one element, we double the element and then prepend that to the result of calling the `doubleAll` function on the tail of the list.

**Step 2.** Actually, there are two things going on here:

1. I want a function that lets me apply another function to each element of a list.
2. In this case, I want that function to be "multiply by 2".

So, now we have two functions, let's do a simple implementation like this:

```
let rec map f list =
    match list with
    | []       -> []
    | hd :: tl -> f hd :: map f tl

let doubleAll list = map (fun x -> x * 2) list
```

**Step 3.** Actually, the idea of `map` is such a common one that it's already built into the F# standard library, see [`List.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.map%5B%27t,%27u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

So, all we need to do is this:

```
let doubleAll list = List.map (fun x -> x * 2) list
```

Comment: Thank you! This clears things up for me. I appreciate you taking the time to explain this out to me so I can understand the process.